# How to install Loki on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-loki

I'm installing [Loki](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/setup/install/helm/install-monolithic/#install-the-monolithic-helm-chart) on my Kubernetes minikube instance.

When I look at my pods I get one running out of three:

```
default       loki-write-0                                  1/1     Running       0          83m
default       loki-write-1                                  0/1     Pending       0          83m
default       loki-write-2                                  0/1     Pending       0          83m
```

`logs` on the *running* pod gives:

```
at least 1 live replicas required, could only find 0 - unhealthy instances
```

`describe` gives on the *running* pod:

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

`describe` on the *dead* pods:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
```

So as you can see, it wants 3 pods but the affinity cannot be satisfied because I'm running minikube which is one node.

How do I tell Loki to run one instance only?

I have this `variables.yaml` file that specified one pod `replication_factor: 1`:

```
cat values.yaml 
loki:
  auth_enabled: false
  commonConfig:
    replication_factor: 1
  storage:
    bucketNames:
      chunks: chunks
      ruler: ruler
      admin: admin
    type: s3
    minio:
      enabled: true
  singleBinary:
    replicas: 1
```

But as you can see it still makes 3 pods anyways.

How do I tell it to make one pod and give that pod the affinity:

```
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: minikube
```

Here is the helm file I used to install Loki:

```
helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
helm install --values values.yaml loki grafana/loki
```

and [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/setup/install/helm/install-monolithic/#install-the-monolithic-helm-chart) is where I got the instruction in the first place.

Comment: Indent of the valeus.yaml may be wrong. `singleBinary` has extra indent comparing with the URL which you mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure that it's value of replica is used for loki deployments ?

Comment: The people that downvoted the question, can you please provide feedback as to why it's downvoted? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pods you listed in your question belong to the Loki-write statefulset, which is controlled by a different parameter in the chart, namely `write.replicas` (see [this reference](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/production/helm/loki/templates/write/statefulset-write.yaml#L23) in the chart code).

Once you change this parameter to 1 a single replica of the write statefulset should be scheduled.